# How can I use a Ionic 3 Cordova plugin in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am attempting to use the [Spotify OAuth](https://github.com/Festify/cordova-spotify-oauth) plugin within an Ionic 4 Capacitor app following [this](https://devdactic.com/ionic-spotify-app-oauth/) tutorial. When I click the signin button I get a `cordova is not defined` error. How can I use this Cordova plugin?

Comment: did you include cordova.js?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph Yes

Answer (score 0):

According to this

> https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/cordova/using-cordova-plugins/

```
npm install cordova-spotify-oauth
npm install cordova-plugin-customurlscheme --variable 
URL_SCHEME=devdacticspotify
```

Then

```
npx cap sync
```

Comment: adding the variable to npm install throws the following error:
Invalid tag name "URL_SCHEME=devdacticspotify": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

Comment: same error here, any solutions yet?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post:
https://www.joshmorony.com/using-cordova-plugins-that-require-install-variables-with-capacitor/

You need to update `app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml` (or `AndroidManifest.xml`) file